# What is the standard encoding of Body on Outlook.MailItem

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I need to ensure that I have the body of a MailItem-Object encoded as UTF-8, but I cannot figure out what the current encoding is and I have not found any notes on this. Even the HTMLBody does not seem to specify this, at least I couldn't find it.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [Outlook MailItem.HTMLBody encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841042/outlook-mailitem-htmlbody-encoding)

Comment: Woops yes ... didn't turn up in search results for this title though, I'm rather sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All strings in the Outlook Object Model are UTF-16; you can easily convert them to UTF-8. . What exactly are you trying to do and why?

Comment: Serialize some data (including the body) from a MailItem-object as JSON and send it to a server that expects UTF-8 - however I realize now that the question more broadly would have to be something like: what happens encoding-wise when I assign the UTF-16 encoded mail-body to a string variable, put that into some object constructor, serialize this object and write the serialized string into a RequestStream.
Chances are I now have some pointless conversion code, but at least the encoding definitely is correct, so everything's fine and you answered the literal question.
Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: If you are using the "string" type in .Net, it also uses UTF-16 encoding, so you are fine. When and if the data needs to be converted to UTF-8, that is when the conversion needs to happen. But that has northing to do with Outlook.